# How to open or convert a .3gpp video file

Tags: audio, video, video-conversion

I'm trying to remove background noise from a video/audio file. I can't even open/import it. Audacity suggested to download FFmpeg, but I am still unable. It says, "Audacity did not recogize this type of file .3gpp. Try installing FFmpeg." I downloaded that, but still nothing. How can I open this file or convert it into a more widely-supported format?

Answer (score 0):

Use this commands:

`ffmpeg -i your-video.3gpp -vn only-audio.wav` for audio-only conversion (Audacity)
`ffmpeg -i your-video.3gpp audio-and-video.mp4` for audio and video (for other programs)

This works perfectly.